# getting updated data from inserted and deleted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have physical tables to hold ids, along with time of inserted, deleted, updated data 
and have my triggers attached (after insert, update and delete) with base table. Its a sort of tracking.

Inserted records and deleted records are fine but problem is that I am not getting any record in base table for updated records!! 
records that are in inserted and deleted both.

Help me if i am missing anything here.

Trigger for insert and update operation :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trArticleAttachmentTrack]
   ON  [dbo].[ArticleAttachment]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO TrackArticleAttachmentTbl (ArticleAttachmentID, ActionOn)
    SELECT i.ArticleAttachmentID, GETDATE() FROM inserted i

END

GO
```

Trigger for delete operation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trArticleAttachmentTrackDelete]
   ON  [dbo].[ArticleAttachment]
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO TrackArticleAttachmentTblRowDel (ArticleAttachmentID, ActionOn)
    SELECT i.ArticleAttachmentID, GETDATE() FROM deleted i

END

GO
```

Query to get output

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN i.ArticleAttachmentID IS NULL THEN 'This is a delete' 
       WHEN  d.ArticleAttachmentID IS NULL THEN 'This is an insert' 
                                        ELSE 'This is an update' 
  END  as Action, 
  * 
FROM 
  TrackArticleAttachmentTbl i
FULL OUTER JOIN 
  TrackArticleAttachmentTblRowDel d
    ON i.ArticleAttachmentID = d.ArticleAttachmentID
```

OUTPUT:

```
This is an update   38  18226   2012-02-19 14:01:52 5   18226   2012-02-19 14:02:01
This is an update   22  18210   2012-02-15 16:38:39 4   18210   2012-02-15 16:39:29
This is an update   13  18201   2012-02-15 12:21:22 2   18201   2012-02-15 12:21:32
This is an update   47  18235   2012-02-19 16:37:54 6   18235   2012-02-19 17:09:53
```

Query to get updated records

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ArticleAttachment 
WHERE ArticleAttachmentID IN (18226,18210,18201,18235)
```

no result for this :(

Comment: How can we help you without seeing your code? Please post your trigger code.

Comment: If you'd provided scripts of the triggers we could help you.

Comment: i have provided the code for triggers and queries with outputs

Comment: How can you tell the difference between an inserted record and an updated record? By the looks of it you expect the update to have a row in both `TrackArticleAttachmentTbl` and `TrackArticleAttachmentTblRowDel`. But that will not be the case. Your updates will only add a row to `TrackArticleAttachmentTbl` and when you later on delete a row it will be added to `TrackArticleAttachmentTblRowDel` which will make your query interpret that row as updated when in fact is is deleted. I think you have to change how you figure out if a row is updated or inserted.

Comment: hi mikeal eriksson i read this alot of placed on net 

There is no updated dynamic table. There is just inserted and deleted. On an UPDATE command, the old data is stored in the deleted dynamic table, and the new values are stored in the inserted dynamic table.

Think of an UPDATE as a DELETE/INSERT combination.

Comment: No it is not. If update was treated like DELETE/INSERT you would get new values for your auto incremented identity columns. It is true however that when you do the update you have rows in both `deleted` and `inserted` tables **but** `trArticleAttachmentTrackDelete` is not called on update. If you want to log something from the `deleted` table when you do an update you should use the `deleted` table in `trArticleAttachmentTrack`.

Comment: so combination of both, will not serve my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The CASE expression does not correctly detect deletes. Try this instead.

```
  CASE WHEN d.ArticleAttachmentID IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'This is a delete' 
       ELSE 'This is an insert or update' 
  END
```

Comment: i used case expression just to clarify things and identify updated, but the (updated records) joining both inserted and deleted, they not there in base table. :(

Comment: If an ID exists in trArticleAttachmentTrackDelete then it was deleted. It won't exist in the ArticleAttachment table.

Comment: Think of an UPDATE as a DELETE/INSERT combination